# setFrame not working properly for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, layer

I am trying to add a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer into my view like this

```
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,300.0f,300.0f)];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

but it doesnt seem to follow the CGRectMake, the layer is 300 in height but not in width, I am not sure why!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was simple, I just had to add `captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Setting the right videoGravity fix the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, as if your view has the wrong dimension for the layer. For this update the size of the view at least to the desired rect:

```
[self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,300.0f,300.0f)];
```

Comment: Clash, I am using ViewController so its supposed to be the entire screen right?

Comment: not necessarily. a vc contains views, that can have different sizes. try `[captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];` and you will see the size of the view.

Comment: Yes I did. And its bigger than 300x300

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are assigning a view outlet to `captureVideoPreviewLayer`,  better to access like `self.captureVideoPreviewLayer`.
If you are doing things in order then setting the frame should work using `CGRectMake`. I have been using it to change the size of preview layer like this.

```
  self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: how about posting your complete code? must be doing something wrong in your code...

Comment: solution was way simpler, I just had to add `captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;` and that fixed it

Comment: Yes it is quite simple, this is the reason it was asked to show your code.